# HTML - Form Tag Inside a Pre Tag

Tags: html, forms, tags, pre

How do you put a form tag inside a preformatted tag?

Thanks

Comment: Um... like this? `<pre><form></form></pre>` but what is this for? I'm not sure I understand

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

```
<!ENTITY % pre.exclusion "IMG|OBJECT|BIG|SMALL|SUB|SUP">
<!ELEMENT PRE - - (%inline;)* -(%pre.exclusion;) -- preformatted text -->
```

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4

A pre element may contain only elements in the group `%inline` (and not all of those). The form element is not one of those elements.